# How to run multiple ssh commands parallel and store outputs into variables

Tags: shell

I have tried to write a shell script which logins in multiple hosts via `ssh`, execute some commands, and print execution summary. So far, I have written a script which works in **sequential** way. But it's slow, I want to rewrite it in a parallel way. I know I can use `&` to run multiple ssh commands parallel, and use "command substitution" to store `subshell` output into variable. But I cannot combine them correctly.

So far, I came out these code. But it still runs in sequential way.

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=( 'host-1' 'host-2' 'host-3' )

cmd='sleep $[ (( $RANDOM % 20 ) + 1) /10 ]s && echo hello world'
i=0
for host in ${hosts[@]}; do
    var1=$(ssh $host $cmd &)
    echo "i = $i"
    outputs[i]="$var1"
    ((i++))
done

echo 'wait'
wait

echo ${outputs[@]}
```

Comment: Oh, also, you most likely want to always use quotes around `"${array[@]}"`, too. without them, the array elements get split on whitespace. Not a problem with hostnames, but in general...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can usefully use variable assignments in the background (with command substitution or not), since background jobs run in a subshell. e.g.

```
foo=x
foo=$(echo y) &
echo "$foo"
```

will print `x` as the second assignment only applies to the subshell.

On the other hand, backgrounding the inside of the command substitution doesn't do what you want either, the shell waits for the command anyway, and you get the tasks executed sequentially:

```
sleepecho() { sleep "$1"; echo "$2"; }
foo=$( sleepecho 5 abc & )      # returns after five seconds
echo "$foo"                     # prints 'abc'
```

What you could do, would be to store the output from the commands in temporary files. This would let the backgrounding work, and might also be better if the output is very long.

```
dir=$(mktemp -d)
for h in "${hosts[@]}" ; do
    ssh "$h" "$cmd" > "$dir/$h" & 
done
wait
do something with "$dir/"*
```

Though there are a number of ready-made solutions for running commands on multiple hosts via `ssh`...

Comment: Yes, this is better than trying to capture the output of the commands in variables. This is also better for the cases where the remote command produces lots of output.

Comment: Your solution is correct but your explanation isn't. The script doesn't attempt to use an assignment done in a subshell from the parent. It attempts to capture the output of a background job, but that is empty because the capture stops when the parent process exits, it doesn't wait for the background job.

Comment: @Gilles, hmm, I misread the original script initially. But seems to me the shell will wait for the command substitution even if its inside is supposedly put to the background. Which leads to what the question stated, the commands run sequentially.